# Tuple looks confusing when returning psutil's functions

Tags: python, tuples, psutil

I am new to Python and trying things out with psutil.
After I get the IO counters from the function , it says that it returns a tuple but then why the returned result looks more like a dictionary ?
I can get the data extracted as tuples but whats with the "Keys " listed for each value in this tuple ? How do I extract them ?
for example what if I want to extract the string "bytes_sent" from the tuple?
Also is this really a Tuple? I can see data enclosed in ( ).

```
 psutil.net_io_counters()
    snetio(bytes_sent=201965381, bytes_recv=571417944, packets_sent=1972681, packets_recv=3515998, errin=0, errout=0, dropin=0, dropout=0)

type (psutil.net_io_counters())
psutil._common.snetio

print result[0]
202031899
```

Comment: its a namedtuple (in python's collection lib), so use snetio.bytes_sent to get bytes sent

Comment: @JTurk My original question was , how to get the Key value in this namedtuple ? for eg: "bytes_sent" . I can extract its value already.

Comment: I was commenting on your question: "why the returned result looks more like a dictionary" and " but whats with the "Keys " listed for each value in this tuple"...to which the answer is collection's namedtuple which is what is given by another user below...

Answer (score 2):

This will be a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).  You can interact with it either as tuple, or by using its attributes.  Best of both worlds and all that.